# Automatically Triggering Airflow DAG in Cloud Composer on GCP without Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project at work where I need to automatically trigger an Airflow DAG in Cloud Composer on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) whenever a .csv file is uploaded to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket. However, there's a restriction in my organisation that **prevents the use of Cloud Functions for this purpose.**

I've successfully implemented a solution using Cloud Functions, but due to organisational constraints, I need to explore alternative methods that are both efficient and cost-effective. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on achieving this without relying on Cloud Functions.

If you've encountered a similar scenario or have ideas on how to set up this file upload trigger without using Cloud Functions, your insights would be incredibly valuable.

Thank you in advance for your help!

As mentioned, I know how to do this using Cloud Functions, but this is prohibited in my organisation, so I need to find alternative methods.

Comment: Do you know why it's forbidden? Because alternative are many, serverless and very cheap, or more legacy and more costly. I can name at least 2 first: Cloud Run and Cloud Workflow -> This one is funny: use an orchestrator to trigger an orchestrator!! I love it! :))

Comment: No, I do not know the specifics. Though, how would Cloud Run/Cloud Workflow be used to trigger the DAG automatically?

Comment: Cloud Run is very similar to Cloud Functions. That's why, if Cloud Functions is not an option, Cloud Run should not also (if your cloud sec team is aware and smart; not sure!!) You can use Eventarc to catch the Cloud Storage event and invoke your Cloud Run, as you invoke your Cloud Functions. The migration should be simple. Cloud Workflow is different. You can also invoke it with eventarc. However Cloud Workflow can only call API. However you can get eventarc message data and call an API, like Airflow API to run your dag. There are more translation work with this solution.

Comment: As a crazy option -  trigger a Cloud Build job.

Answer (score 0):

Something I can think of is Polling with a Time-Based DAG

Set up a DAG in Airflow that runs on a regular schedule (e.g., every 5 minutes).
Within the DAG, use a GoogleCloudStorageListOperator to list the files in your GCS bucket.
Compare the current file list with a previously stored list.
If a new file appears, trigger the necessary downstream Airflow tasks or a different DAG.

hope this help :)

ref : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_list_operator/index.html